# Как рассчитать время работы кода? TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

```
#end_time=time.time()-start_time()
#TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

import time

parts=[]
res=0

start_time=time.time()

a=int(input())

for i in range(a):
    res+=(2**i)*i
    parts.append(((2**i)*i))


print(parts)
print(res)

end_time=time.time()-start_time()
print(end_time,'end_time')
```

Comment: Уберите скобки `start_time()`  -> `start_time`

Comment: Спасибо, работает